# Provide Internet connection to Virtual Machines on Hyper-V

Tags: networking, hyper-v, virtual-machines

Our Office LAN - 192.168.1.1/24
Gateway - 192.168.1.5 (A Microsoft ISA 2006 Server)
DNS - 192.168.1.4 (DC)

We are having Hyper-V server running and there are several Virtual Machines on that server.
I have created 2 Virtual Networks on Hyper-V server -
1. External (Bound with my Server Ethernet);
2. Internal Only;
So my 'Network Connections' shows me three adapters - LAN 1 (Onboard Ethernet); LAN 2(External); LAN 3 (Internal Only).

I want the VMs to share the Internal Only LAN, have different series of IP [say 192.168.0.1/24] and must be isolated from office LAN.

But my criterias are folowing -
1.Provide Internet connections to VMs
2.RDC to VMs, multiple session required [VMs will have Windows server OS]

Is it really possible or my thinking is absurd? Need suggestion.

Thanks and regards,

Arindam

---

For more clarification I tried to make my office network diagram. Here it is -

[image]

Comment: For more clarification I tried to make my office network diagram. Here it is -

 Link: [http://]i[dot]stack[dot]imgur[dot]com/KknOD[dot]png

Answer (score 2):

With the exception of "provide internet connections to VMs", everything you've described will work "out of the box".

If by internet connecitons to VMs, as in you want people to be able to RDP to the VMs that are not on your office LAN, yes its possible but you need to explain a little more about your internet conneciton.  Is it a range of IPs?  Is it NAT and you need to configure a few servers, etc...

Splitting the VMs to a new subnet is dooable, but you need to add some more details about your DHCP server.

**Edit 1**

Based on your diagram, that looks relatively easy to implement.

1. Add another router for 192.168.0/24
2. Ensure the routers, 192.168.0/24 and 192.168.1/24 can talk to each other (static routes, or otherwise, PS depending on the router you alreayd have it may be possible to just add it on the same device).
3. Ensure that DHCP requests are being forwarded by your new router.
4. Add a new subnet for your machines in the DHCP server.  You can ensure only Hyper-V machines are getting IP addresses on that subnet by creating a special class for them, more on the MAC addresses used by your Hyper-V install [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/01/20/hyper-v-r2-mac-address-management.aspx).
5. Ensure your ISA server knows of this new subnet and allows internet traffic for it.